# How to completely remove Personal Guard 2009?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, spyware

I have become infected with the Personal Guard 2009 malware.  How do I get rid of this pest?

Answer (score 1):

There is one more [removal discussion here](http://www.spywarewarrior.com/viewtopic.php?t=31419&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=).

And, I wondered, if [RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) would work on this...
But, there is [this other discussion](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic258646.html) that surprised me (suggests using [RootRepeal](http://rootrepeal.googlepages.com/)).
If you choose to try RevoUninstaller (or have already done so), do tell us what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on how to remove [Personal Guard 2009.](http://www.2-spyware.com/remove-personal-guard-2009.html)

Answer (score 0):

After you follow the above instructions, grab the tool about midway down on this page [SmitfraudFix](http://siri.geekstogo.com/SmitfraudFix.php) and run it in safe mode.  Another tool is "Combofix", but it's licensing specifically states that it is to be used only with instructors on a specific forum.

Before you do anything, clear all temp files using ATF Cleaner or CCleaner.  Two reasons for this: 1) It makes it easier on cleanup tools, 2) many rogue installer files live in temp files directories.

Also - run a scan with [MalwareBytes](http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html?part=dl-10804572&subj=dl&tag=button).  This will clue you into any other problems.  Both MalwareBytes and Combofix will also clue you into a rootkit infection - if that's the case, let us know.  Rootkit cleanup is a little more targeted.